# Unable to push array to Google Sheets

Tags: node.js, google-sheets, google-drive-api, google-sheets-api, google-api-nodejs-client

I am trying to push the contents of the array I send a function to a newly created google sheet. I am getting API errors when trying to push data to the spreadsheet I am not too sure what to do to resolve this not really understanding much of the documentation on this topic I believe I did everything right struggling to get this working though.

If I am able to merge the create event to push the content of the array I would like to understand how to do that instead as that would be better than creating then updating.

If anyone could help me solve my problem getting data onto the spreadsheet I would appreciate it very much

```js
const {google} = require('googleapis');
const auth = new google.auth.GoogleAuth({
    keyFile: './my-project.json',
    scopes: [
        'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive',
        'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive.file',
        'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/spreadsheets'
    ],
});
google.options({auth: auth.getClient()});
 
/* Example of array received from function 
const transData = [
    {
        "issuer":"John Cena",
        "time": "7-27-2022",
        "id":"e0c69748-c47a-48ad-80f9-90b181627963",
        "receiver":"Tyrese Jenkins",
        "message":"This is Placeholder message text",
        "type":"remove",
        "amount":10,
        "title":"Test Title"
    },
    //... duplicated
]
*/
const createSpreadsheet = async (transData) => {
    let dateTime = new Date().toLocaleString()
    let label = `Placeholder - ${dateTime}`
    const sheets = google.sheets('v4');
    
    //Create a new spreadsheet to push array dataset to (Works)
    sheets.spreadsheets.create({
        auth: auth,
        resource: { properties: { "title": label } }
    }, function (err, response) {
        if (err) return console.log('The API returned an error: ' + err);
 
        const sheetID = response.data.spreadsheetId
        const drive = google.drive({ version: "v3", auth: auth });
        
        //Update permissions of file so anyone with URL can view but NOT edit (Works)
        drive.permissions.create({
            fileId: sheetID,
            requestBody: {
                role: 'reader',
                type: 'anyone'
            }
        }, function (error, res) {
            if (error) return console.log(error);
            
            //Attempting to push array to fill the spreadsheet with data. (API Errors)
            sheets.spreadsheets.values.append({
                auth: auth,
                spreadsheetId: sheetID,
                range: 'Sheet1!A:H',
                resource: {//Invalid JSON payload received. Unknown name "type" at 'data.values[125]': Cannot find field. (for each field in array only posted 1 for example)
                    values: transData
                },
              /*resource: { Error: Invalid values[0][0]: struct_value 
                    values: [transData]
                },
                */
                valueInputOption: 'USER_ENTERED',
            }, (e, r) => {
                if (e) return console.log('The API returned an error: ' + e);
                
                console.log(r)
            });
        });
        
    });
})
```

Comment: Quote  and describe the error as written in [mcve]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

#### Modification points:

- From your showing script, if the value of `transData` is as follows, unfortunately, this value cannot be directly used in the request body of "Method: spreadsheets.values.append". In this case, it is required to convert it to a 2-dimensional array. I thought that this might be the reason for your issue of `Invalid JSON payload received. Unknown name "type" at 'data.values[125]': Cannot find field. (for each field in the array only posted 1 for example)`.

  ```
    const transData = [
        {
            "issuer":"John Cena",
            "time": "7-27-2022",
            "id":"e0c69748-c47a-48ad-80f9-90b181627963",
            "receiver":"Tyrese Jenkins",
            "message":"This is Placeholder message text",
            "type":"remove",
            "amount":10,
            "title":"Test Title"
        },
        //... duplicated
    ]
  ```

When these points are reflected in your script, how about the following modification?

#### From:

```
sheets.spreadsheets.values.append({
    auth: auth,
    spreadsheetId: sheetID,
    range: 'Sheet1!A:H',
    resource: {
        values: transData
    },
  /*resource: { Error: Invalid values[0][0]: struct_value 
        values: [transData]
    },
    */
    valueInputOption: 'USER_ENTERED',
}, (e, r) => {
    if (e) return console.log('The API returned an error: ' + e);
    
    console.log(r)
});
```

#### To:

```
const keys = Object.keys(transData[0]);
const values = [keys, ...transData.map((o) => keys.map((k) => o[k] || ""))];
sheets.spreadsheets.values.append(
  {
    auth: auth, // <--- Added
    spreadsheetId: sheetID,
    range: "A1",
    resource: { values },
    valueInputOption: "USER_ENTERED",
  },
  (e, r) => {
    if (e) return console.log("The API returned an error: " + e);
    console.log(r.data);
  }
);
```

- In this modification, the value of `transData` is converted to a 2-dimensional array, and it is used as the request body.
- In this modification, the header row is added. If you don't want to add the header row, please modify as follows.

  - From

    ```
      const values = [keys, ...transData.map((o) => keys.map((k) => o[k] || ""))];
    ```
  - To

    ```
      const values = transData.map((o) => keys.map((k) => o[k] || ""));
    ```

#### Reference:

- [Method: spreadsheets.values.append](https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/reference/rest/v4/spreadsheets.values/append)

Comment: I tried your edit and now get the error `TypeError: d.request is not a function` Ill play around with it and see if I can resolve it

Comment: @Rishi Thank you for replying. I have to apologize for my poor English skill. Unfortunately, from `I tried your edit and now get the error TypeError: d.request is not a function Ill play around with it and see if I can resolve it`, I cannot understand your current situation. Can I ask you about the detail of your current issue? For example, what is `d.request`? When I tested my proposed script using your value of `transData`, no error occurs. I think that this is due to my poor skill. I deeply apologize for both my poor English skill and poor skill again.

Comment: @Rishi By the way, I cannot still know whether you are directly using the value of `transData` as the request body. How about this? And, can you provide your whole script for correctly replicating your issue of `TypeError: d.request is not a function`?

Comment: so `d.request` im not too sure what it is. The error was returned from the `sheets.spreadsheets.values.append` function. The API returned the error. So it isnt pushing the data to the spreadsheet still

Comment: @Rishi Thank you for replying. When I tested my proposed script using your value of `transData`, no error occurs. I think that this is due to my poor skill. I deeply apologize for my poor skill again. In order to correctly replicate your issue of `so d.request im not too sure what it is. `, can you provide your whole script for correctly replicating it? By this, I would like to confirm your current issue.

Comment: @Rishi By the way, in your current script, a new Spreadsheet could be created?

Comment: Yeah the new spreadsheet is created first, then I update the permissions so anyone with the link can view it. Then it is trying to push the data but I am failing on that step. The code above shouuld be everything try using the `transdata` from here and see if it works https://pastebin.com/pPytmwHZ

Comment: @Rishi Thank you for replying. I have to apologize for my poor English skill, again. Unfrotuynately, I think that [https://pastebin.com/pPytmwHZ](https://pastebin.com/pPytmwHZ) is the sample data of `transdata`. I asked about your current script for correctly replicating your current issue of `TypeError: d.request is not a function`. By the way, even when your provided new value, I confirmed that the script worked. I apologize for this.

Comment: d.request is not a function is happening because I am building the ts into compiled js. But the error itself was displayed from the api. If you look at the append function if their is a error it prints and it printed this 
`The API returned an error: TypeError: d.request is not a function`

Comment: @Rishi Thank you for replying. From `d.request is not a function is happening because I am building the ts into compiled js. But the error itself was displayed from the api. If you look at the append function if their is a error it prints and it printed this The API returned an error: TypeError: d.request is not a function`, unfortunately, I couldn't understand your current issue. I apologize for this. Can you provide your whole script for correctly replicating your current issue?

Comment: I uploaded the project [here](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1XHUaCAP0wgIv8q2P4btd8eMcXSSyoy4m/view?usp=sharing) 
In the root run `npm i` and `npm build` when you do any changes, and in the dist/server folder put your google service json and call it `my-project.json` then just cd into dist/server and run `node *.js` whatever the file name is

Comment: I appreciate you helping me out @Tanaike

Comment: Sorry I had to reupload as I put my json key in their by mistake [Download Here](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1Y9RJR76Rm0KgvQFuWCSPyKXkadSg4Nso/view?usp=sharing)

Comment: @Rishi Thank you for replying. From your provided script, I could notice my miscopied script. I apologize for it. So, I updated the modified script. Could you please confirm it?

Comment: Perfect yeah that worked, is their a way to control which order the sheet is generated? (Like the order the array leys appear in the sheet)

Comment: @Rishi About `is their a way to control which order the sheet is generated? (Like the order the array leys appear in the sheet)`, I would like to support you. So, in this case, I would like to propose posting it as a new question. Because this is different from your question. If you can cooperate to resolve your new issue, I'm glad. Can you cooperate to resolve your new question?